# How do I specify classification in h2o random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I am looking all over the internet on how to specify classification in h2o.randomForest. Whatever I could find says that there is parameter "classification" which we can set to TRUE. But it is not there anymore as per the h2o package documentation.

SEE here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf

When I run this h2o.randomForest on my data in which the target variable is a binary 1-0 variable, it assumes regression.

I am not sure how to tell it that I want to do classifcation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What distinction do you make between binary classification and binary regression? If your response variable is binary, there is only one possible random variable, namely a Bernoulli. On the other hand, running a random forest on a binary response is effectively performing classification...

Comment: It depends on the y argument, which is I guess what @Anvi said in his answer. See the h2o.randomForest documentation in your reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using R you need to use as.factor to convert your binary 1-0 variables, and if you are using Flow, you need to convert your binary 1-0 variables to enums. After you do this, H2O's random forest will automatically recognize this as a classification problem.

Thanks,

Avni